# Cannot change caption for a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I tried to change the caption "related posts" of https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-posts-thumbnails/ to something else.

I tried to change the value of `$top_text` to `<h3>THIS IS NEW CAPTION:</h3>` but it does not work. Why ?

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name:  Related Posts Thumbnails
     * Plugin URI:   http://wordpress.shaldybina.com/plugins/related-posts-thumbnails/
     * Description:  Showing related posts thumbnails under the post.
     * Version:      1.5.2
     * Author:       Maria Shaldybina
     * Author URI:   http://shaldybina.com/
     */

    /*
       Copyright 2010  Maria I Shaldybina

      This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
      it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
      the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
      (at your option) any later version.

      This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
      but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
      MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
      GNU General Public License for more details.
    */
    class RelatedPostsThumbnails {
      /* Default values. PHP 4 compatible */
      var $single_only       = '1';
      var $auto              = '1';
      var $top_text          = '<h3>NEW CAPTION:</h3>';
      var $number            = 3;
      var $relation          = 'categories';
      var $poststhname       = 'thumbnail';
      var $background        = '#FFFFFF';
      var $hoverbackground   = '#EEEEEF';
      var $border_color      = '#DDDDDD';
      var $font_color        = '#333333';
      var $font_family       = 'Arial';
      var $font_size         = '12';
      var $text_length       = '100';
      var $excerpt_length    = '0';
      var $custom_field      = '';
      var $custom_height     = '100';
      var $custom_width      = '100';
      var $text_block_height = '75';
      var $thsource          = 'post-thumbnails';
      var $categories_all    = '1';
      var $devmode           = '0';
      var $output_style      = 'div';
      var $post_types        = array( 'post' );
      var $custom_taxonomies = array();

      protected $wp_kses_rp_args = array( 

                'h1' => array(),
                'h2' => array(),
                'h3' => array(),
                'h4' => array(),
                'h5' => array(),
                'h6' => array(),
                'strong' => array(),
              );

      function __construct() {
        // initialization
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'related-posts-thumbnails', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/locale' );
        $this->default_image = esc_url( plugins_url( 'img/default.png', __FILE__ ) );

        // Compatibility for old default image path.
        if ( $this->is_old_default_img() )
          update_option( 'relpoststh_default_image', $this->default_image );

        if ( get_option( 'relpoststh_auto', $this->auto ) ) {
          add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'auto_show' ) );
        }

        add_action( 'admin_menu',  array( $this, 'admin_menu' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'related-posts-thumbnails' , array( $this, 'get_html' ) );

        $this->wp_version = get_bloginfo( 'version' );
      }
```

Comment: Have you cleared the cache, both of the server and your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just changed the default value for `$top_text`. Modifying a plugin directly like that is not a good idea, because the changes will be lost when updating.

There's quite a bit more code in that plugin, and going through it, I see that there is an options page where that value is set. It seems like you should just change the value of the caption text to `<h3>THIS IS NEW CAPTION:</h3>` there.

It is possible to alter option values programmatically, so you should be able to add this to your `functions.php` to alter the value on the fly:

```
function wpse241711_related_posts_thumbnails_filter_top_text( $top_text ) {
    return '<h3>THIS IS NEW CAPTION:</h3>';
}
add_filter( 'option_relpoststh_top_text', 'wpse241711_related_posts_thumbnails_filter_top_text' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Because if you have a deeper look in the plugin, you will see `$top_text` is only used when the option `relpoststh_top_text` is not set. It looks like there is a settings page, where you can edit this text.